# Can Phabricator user type custom feild auto add to Subscribers?

Tags: phabricator

I custom a user type field in a Phabricator form. When I use it to create a task, the user in that field isn't added to subscribers. Can Phabricator user type custom field auto add to Subscribers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first welcome to Slackoverflow!

according to Phabricator [documentation](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/custom_fields/#basic-custom-fields), I comprehend that you can not connect the fields with any action, other than saving them in database. If you want to have events connected with the field, you need to program the field as an [extension](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/custom_fields/#advanced-custom-fields).

Comment: I'm not a phper. so...Thank you for answer.